# Using the keyboard from the lock screen in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, lockscreen

What I need to be able to do is Edit a text view from the lock screen.
So far I have a widget on the lock screen with a text view that is editable and looks like an edit text view. It is also focusable.

However, when I click on it to edit it no keyboard comes up. Is the keyboard locked from use in the lock screen? Is there any way to pull up a keyboard from the lock screen to edit the text view?

Thanks